# Are there any Monero podcasts?

Tags: monero-community

Are there any Monero-specific podcasts or episodes related to Monero in a more general podcast?

I'm specifically asking about audio recording rather than videos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Monero-specific podcasts:**

- [Monero missives](http://monero.org/missives/) : 11 episodes are available on Monero official site. Last one is from March 19th, 2015
- [Monero Monitor](https://moneromonitor.com/) : a podcast started in March 2017 by [bigreddmachine](https://monero.stackexchange.com/users/363/bigreddmachine)

**Episodes:**

- [The Bitcoin Game](https://letstalkbitcoin.com/blog/category/the-bitcoin-game) : core member [fluffyponyza](https://monero.stackexchange.com/users/47/fluffyponyza) was the invitee of a double episode in 2017 ([part1](https://letstalkbitcoin.com/blog/post/the-bitcoin-game-42-riccardo-fluffypony-spagni), [part2](https://letstalkbitcoin.com/blog/post/the-bitcoin-game-43-moneros-fluffypony-part-2))